# Applying Group By on multiple foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `Jobs` that has five columns:

```
Skill1, Skill2, Skill3, Skill4, Skill5
```

Each column is linked with a same table `Job_Skill_Cat` as a foreign key.

I want to count number of jobs related to each skill.

The output should be like

```
Java (5)jobs
C++ (23)jobs
Python (34)jobs
```

I have tried my best but I was only able to fetch number of jobs related to `skill1`.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(JOB_ID), skill_name  
FROM
    jobs 
INNER JOIN
    job_skill_cat ON jobs.emplj_skill1 = job_skill_cat.skill_id 
GROUP BY
    skill_name
```

Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot the data and `join`:

```
select jsc.skill_name, count(*) 
from ((select job_id, skill1 as skill from jobs) union all
      (select job_id, skill2 as skill from jobs) union all
      (select job_id, skill3 as skill from jobs) union all
      (select job_id, skill4 as skill from jobs) union all
      (select job_id, skill5 as skill from jobs) 
     ) j join
     job_skill_cat jsc
     on j.emplj_skill1 = jsc.skill_id
group by jsc.skill_name;
```

In Oracle 12C+, you can use a lateral join for this purpose instead of `union all`.

Basically, you have a poor data model.  You should have a `job_skills` table with one row per job and per skill.

Answer (score 0):

You need `UNION ALL` & do the `JOIN` :

```
SELECT skill_id, skill_name, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT Skill1 AS Skill
      FROM Jobs J UNION ALL
      SELECT Skill2
      FROM Jobs J UNION ALL
      SELECT Skill3
      FROM Jobs J UNION ALL
      SELECT Skill4
      FROM Jobs J UNION ALL
      SELECT Skill5
      FROM Jobs J
     ) j INNER JOIN 
     job_skill_cat jsc
     ON jsc.skill_id = j.Skill
GROUP BY skill_id, skill_name;
```

Comment: @AliTahir. . . Include that column in `GROUP BY`  clause.

Answer (score 0):

First we convert the data into rows and then group it and count the number of skills

```
 WITH c AS (
 SELECT DISTINCT job_Id, skill
 FROM jobs j CROSS APPLY
      ( VALUES (skill1), (skill2), (skill3), (skill4), (skill5)
      ) jb (skill)
 ) 
SELECT skill,COUNT(job_Id)
FROM c
GROUP BY skill ;
```